# Magento Product CSV Import error

Tags: product, import, csv

I'm having kinda serious issue with CSV product import.
When I'm trying to import only one product from CSV (for testing reasons)
I get following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`admin_knygynas`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ), query
>   was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
>   (`attribute_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`)

Got this issue first time, searched where I can, but no solutions so far, sitting on this one for hours. I see that it tries to insert `VALUES(?,?,?)` into product media gallery entity, and it doesn't make any sense.

I exported CSV from Magento 1.7.2 version, and trying to import to 1.9.2. But i was reading somewhere that it doesn't make any difference.
I did all the steps. Created missing attributes, imported categories with another module so everything there should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution! In the CSV file i have noticed that there is an attribute called _media_attribute_id, exported a product from my default site, and seen that it was 720 and in my other csv file it was 90.. So i have changed the id from 90 to 720 and it fixed my problem!